# Refreshing an SSL certificate in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https

I'm using a letsencrypt certificate on an Express server to enable https. The certificate is automatically renewed by a cron job running certbot-auto periodically.

Express reads the certificate file at startup. Do I need to do something to let Express know when the certificate is renewed, or will it pick up the changes automatically? If I need to manually refresh it, how would I do so without restarting the whole app?

Comment: You might be able to pull it off by watching the cert files, newing up your server again, stopping the old one, and starting the new one... in that order. It feels really complex though - I personally tend to terminate SSL at nginx or haproxy to avoid dealing with https in my node apps. I trust the private network between the proxy and my node server. Then you can issue reload signals or restart those proxies/load balancers super quick